# What's the opposite word of "strict parents"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, adjectives, antonyms

I am a non-native English speaker. 
When I was writing an English essay, a question came up my mind.
Which word is better "carefree parents" or "easy-going parents" when I want to compare with "strict parents"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are exactly the opposite of "strict", I would call them **"liberal"** or even **"permissive"** depending on the intended connotation.

> - [**"liberal"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liberal)  (adj) not strict, not opposed to new ideas or ways of behaving that are not traditional or widely accepted.
> - [**"permissive"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permissive) -
>   (adj) deficient in firmness or control, giving people a lot of freedom or too much freedom to do what they want to do.

When we use "permissive" there is usually a certain criticism implied.

Comment: I think "Permissive" is better, as "liberal" might be taken to be describing their political viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in my area of the United States, the word of choice seems to be [***lenient***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lenient) - per the linked definition, “1.  agreeably tolerant; permissive; indulgent”.

Answer (score 0):

A very lenient parenting style I only recently discovered has been labelled: [Free-range parenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-range_parenting). So some might be called **Free-range parents**. Their children are commonly called **Free-range children**, and there are documentaries on YouTube about that particular social phenomenon.